# What is the purpose of the environment variable asl.log?

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

I run Windows 7.

I notice that there's an environment variable called `asl.log`.  What is this thing? 
Who puts it there?

What's the purpose of it?

I searched and found only references to MacOS and Apple System Log.
But as I said, this is a Windows7 machine from Dell.  It doesn't run MacOS.

Comment: Hint: Apple iTunes

Comment: Yep, I have it on an XP laptop with iTunes installed too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have it too in W7.
A SYSTEM environment variable asl.log with the value Destination=file

Found this reference in the register:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Apple Inc.\ASL\filenames\asl.log
value REG_SZ asl.103843_28May11.log

I am pretty sure it is an Apple thing.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, I deleted it, iTunes still works fine, it didn't come back.

Apparently, it's an old Apple logging thing:

http://commandlinemac.blogspot.com/2008/12/apple-system-logger.html
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging